# meteor + react "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

Im using Meteor + React and "this.props.thing.source" is a string for a mongodb _id.

The "findOne()" function is one of Meteor's.  As you can see it works fine when I pass in the string of the ID itself, but I get an undefined error when passing in the variable, even though that variable renders out that same string.

**In this code:**

```
Thing = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    thing: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>Display: {Things.findOne(this.props.thing.source).data}</li>
        <li>Display: {Things.findOne("emq6M4WbJeRvkA6Q3").data}</li>
        <li>Source: {this.props.thing.source}</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

**This does NOT work:**

Display: {Things.findOne(this.props.thing.source).data}

**This works:**

Display: {Things.findOne("emq6M4WbJeRvkA6Q3").data}

**And this correctly renders "emq6M4WbJeRvkA6Q3":**

Source: {this.props.thing.source}

**The ERROR I am getting:**

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

Comment: Probably because `this.props.thing.source` is not equal to that hash code, meaning `findOne` returns `undefined`, so accessing the `data` property throws an error.

Comment: just figured it out, and it is related to not equaling the string ... i found out not all of the Things has a value for .source, so on some it was undefined ... now im checking if there is a string value first, and only then performing the find.

Comment: That's precisely what I meant. When you used the hard coded string, `findOne` returned an object with the `data` property. However, when you used the variable, `findOne` was returning `undefined`, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because of whatever `Things.findOne()` returns is `undefined`.

You say that calling above function with the `this.props.thing.source` does not work, which is wrong but since you're not mentioning how the rendering of your `Thing` component takes place your best bet to find the error is the way you're passing the prop `this.props.thing.source`/what you're passing to your component.

I made a quick copy-paste example that illustrates and also made your component work in a JSFiddle

```
var Things = {
    findOne: function (thingSource) {
        if (thingSource) {
            return {
                data: 'It did work!'
            };
        }
        return undefined;
    }
}

var Thing = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        thing: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello {Things.findOne(this.props.thing.source).data}</div>;
    }
});

React.render(<Hello thing={{source: true}} />, document.body);
```

A working example with your exact component can be [found here](http://jsfiddle.net/eveu16ma/)

Comment: took a look at this and updated my questions with some details.  im using Meteor+React so "Things" is a Meteor defined Mongo collection, and "findOne()" is the provided function, not one I created.  "this.props.thing.source" is a variable containing a string of a Mongo _id.  it correctly renders a string of an _id, but the find function doesn't work when I use this variable, I get undefined error for the data property.

Comment: just figured it out, and it is related to the string ... i found out not all of the Things has a value for .source, so on some it was undefined ... now im checking if there is a string value first, and only then performing the find.